# htaccess redirect 301 is working but RewriteRule is not

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Before I used `redirect 301` statement.
Now I'm in a position where I need to use the `RewriteRule` statement to make use of the flags (redirecting without the query string),
but for some reason, it's not working.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Директивы (строки) между `BEGIN WordPress` и `END WordPress`
# созданы автоматически и подлежат изменению только через фильтры WordPress.
# Сделанные вручную изменения между этими маркерами будут перезаписаны.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


#this is working
redirect 301 /bad-link/  http://localhost:8000/

#this is not working
RewriteRule ^test/bad-link.*$ "http://localhost:8000" [NC,QSD,L,R=301]

#this is also not working
RewriteRule "test/bad-link" "http://localhost:8000" [R=301]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: And "is not working" means _what_ exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the directives in the wrong order. The mod_rewrite redirects (ie. `RewriteRule` directives) need to go *before* the WordPress front-controller rewrites. By placing them after the WordPress directives they are never going to be processed since the request has already been rewritten to the WP front-controller (`index.php`) and processing stops.

You should not edit the code inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` / `# END WordPress` code block as WordPress itself tries to maintain this code block and your edits can get overwritten.

You should place your `RewriteRule` 301 redirect directives *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker. You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive that occurs later, inside the WordPress code block.

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive would have "worked" because it is not dependent on the ordering of directives in relation to the other mod_rewrite directives. Different Apache modules run independently and at different times during the request, regardless of the order of the directives in the config file. mod_rewrite runs *before* mod_alias and the `Redirect` always runs regardless of the outcome of the preceding mod_rewrite directives (unless they trigger an external redirect).

In other words:

```
# External redirects...
RewriteRule ^test/bad-link http://localhost:8000/ [NC,QSD,R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
: etc.
```

Note that the `.*$` at the end of your regex is superfluous.

NB: Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: Many thanks to you, the redirect works, but now everything after 'test/bad-link' is been redirected like ( test/bad-link/good-link) how can i make the redirect only for this link test/bad-link

Comment: @МохамедРусланович To match `test/bad-link` only then append a `$` (end-of-string anchor) to the end of the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (regex). ie. `^test/bad-link$` instead of `^test/bad-link`. (I was just repeating the regex you were using in the question as you didn't actually state what URL you were trying to match.)