# .htaccess in wordpress is not implementing the redirect from www to non-www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

am working on wordpress. And i want to apply a redirect from www to non-www.
There is many solutions online, but non of them worked for me, maybe because htaccess in wordpress works differently?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Директивы (строки) между `BEGIN WordPress` и `END WordPress`
# созданы автоматически и подлежат изменению только через фильтры WordPress.
# Сделанные вручную изменения между этими маркерами будут перезаписаны.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.eepir\.oxem\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://eepir.oxem.ru/$1 [L,R=302]



</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This is my code, i actually tried to post the rule outside of # BEGIN WORDPRESS but no result

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.eepir\.oxem\.ru [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://eepir.oxem.ru/$1 [L,R=302]
> ```

You've put these "redirect" directives in the wrong place. They need to go at the top of the file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.

By placing them after the WordPress front-controller then they are never going to be processed for anything other than existing static assets because the request has already been routed to `/index.php`. At which point processing is stopped.

You should never manually edit the code between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comment markers since this code block is maintained by WordPress itself and your changes will likely get overwritten.

... but I covered all this in your question from yesterday?
[htaccess redirect 301 is working but RewriteRule is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68928580/htaccess-redirect-301-is-working-but-rewriterule-is-not)

You also need to configure WordPress itself to use the non-www hostname. ie. `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` - which should both be set in the dashboard.

> maybe because htaccess in wordpress works differently

`.htaccess` works the same with WordPress as anything else. `.htaccess` doesn't really have much to do with WordPress itself.

---

**UPDATE:** It seems `www.eepir.oxem.ru` has no DNS configured so the request does not even reach your server (for the redirect to occur). You need to configure the appropriate `A` record for `www.eepir.oxem.ru` in the DNS, as you have done for `eepir.oxem.ru` and configure your server to accept requests to `www.eepir.oxem.ru` (if not already). Then your redirect should work.

Comment: Maybe it is, but i thought this is a different issue sence only this kind of redirects is not working, even if i put before #BEGIN WordPress(

Comment: @МохамедРусланович Is `www.eepir.oxem.ru` your actual domain? If so then your server is not even responding to the request (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN)... if the request does not reach your server then your server cannot redirect it.

Comment: it is our domain, its protected with login and password, and am not allowed to share them tbh.

Comment: I understand you now.
am afraid that this question was useless, my bad am sorry

Comment: There are no DNS records for `www.eepir.oxem.ru` so the request does not reach your server.

Comment: should i delete it? or maybe point to yesterday question and mark as duplicated?

Comment: No, leave the question. I've updated my answer with the additional steps that need to be taken to point the hostname to your server.

Comment: Thank you again )) and sorry for the unprofessional question